# AngularJS - Fire $timeout event on ng-change only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I have an ng-change on an input field in html that's bound to a scope variable.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-change="change()" required>

var change = function(){ redraw_graph()}
```

Now when I change the input box, it redraws the graph for every new character I write. I want to have a delay (N seconds), so angular will wait before the user is done typing before the ng-change event fires. And if there are multiple ng-change events fired, it cancels the earlier ones and only executes the latest ones.

I've incorporated the delay with a timeout, but after N seconds the ng-change event still fires more than once. I've solved this problem before, but I can't figure out how to do it currently.

Comment: Cancel the existing `$timeout` before invoking a new one.

Answer (score 11):

To me it seems like what you're asking for is already built into AngularJS. Thus, if you make use of the the [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) directive you can use the `debounce` property:

`ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"`

**To quote the docs**

> .."/or a debouncing delay so that the actual update only takes place
>   when a timer expires; this timer will be reset after another change
>   takes place."

**Working sample**

```js
  angular.module('optionsExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.user = {
          name: 'say'
        };
      }
  ]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ngModelOptions-directive-debounce-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="optionsExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="userForm">
      Name:
      <input type="text" 
             name="userName" 
             ng-model="user.name" 
             ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />
      <button ng-click="userForm.userName.$rollbackViewValue(); user.name=''">Clear</button>
      <br />
    </form>
    <pre>user.name = <span ng-bind="user.name"></span></pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Blackhole's suggestion, you can work this out by cancelling your original $timeout.

Here is how you would do it:

```
var timer;

$scope.change = function(){
   $timeout.cancel( timer );

   timer = $timeout(function() {
             redraw_graph()
           },2000);
 }
```

Check below plunker to see how it works. An alert box (only one) will popup 2 seconds after you are done with all your changes on the input field. That is, if you change the input field before 2 seconds, you delay the popup by another 2 seconds.

http://plnkr.co/edit/v08RYwCDVtymNrgs48QZ?p=preview

**EDIT**

While above is one method of doing it, AngularJS has come up with its own implementation for this particular feature in v1.3+. [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) can be used.

Comment: With this approach, you always get the newest value, if I am reading the code correctly. This is pretty cool when you want only yhe newest value, it works the other way around comparing it to the debounce value of `ng-model-options` and if this works for your use case, this is a valid option. Although, as I recall, `ng-model-options` also has a delay option doing this for you!

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly check out UnderscoreJS, which has `.debounce()` and `.throttle()`

Comment: `debounce` is already included in angular's `ng-model-options` no need for underscore (even though it is a cool library)

Comment: Total agree with Rohan, underscore does many cool things, but is totally unnessecary for this use case for angularJs has the `ng-model-options` that handle this stuff for you, instead of bloating your controller/service even more!